# How can I find the fall velocity of a sphere when it is falling in a fluid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, projectile, drag

The problem is as follows:

> A steel sphere falls inside of a beaker containing a fluid whose force
>   exerted on the sphere is given by $kv$. Assuming that the sphere
>   starts from rest. Calculate the falling speed.

The alternatives given by my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{mg}{4K}\left(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\right)\\
2.&\frac{mg}{2K}\left(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\right)\\
3.&\frac{mg}{K}e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\\
4.&\frac{mg}{2K}e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\\
5.&\frac{mg}{K}\left(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\right)\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I assess this problem?. Since all alternatives appear an exponential I believe the approach does involve the use of drag.

The forces acting in the object would be as follows?.

$F_{net}=mg-kv$

But I'm stuck there. I'm assuming that there's an integral which will make the exponential to appear. But I don't know how to get there. Can someone help me?.

I don't know exactly how to relate it with the fact that the object begins from rest. How would it be?.

Comment: What is difference between $K$ and $k$?

Comment: Is this not a physics problem? Try Physics.SE.

Comment: @Tucker I think they are the same thing, cus after solving the diff eq,  i noticed you get no"K" but only "k"

Comment: well @NamanKumar it does involve solving an ODE so i guess OP's not wrong...

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the Physics Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
F_{\text{net}} &=ma=m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}&=mg-kv\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{k}{m}v&=g\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[v\exp(\frac{k}{m}t)\right]&=g\exp(\frac{k}{m}t)\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
v(t)\exp(\frac{k}{m}t)-v(0)=\frac{mg}{k}\left(\exp(\frac{k}{m}t)-1\right)\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
v(t)&=v(0)\exp(-\frac{k}{m}t)+\frac{mg}{k}\left(1-\exp(-\frac{k}{m}t)\right)\\
\end{align*}

If the object initially has zero velocity then $v(0)=0$ and

\begin{align*}
v(t)&=\frac{mg}{k}\left(1-\exp(-\frac{k}{m}t)\right)\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

We know that net force can be expressed as: 
$$F_{net}=m\dfrac{dv}{dx}$$
Therefore we have: 
$$m\dfrac{dv}{dx}=mg-kv$$
$$\dfrac{dv}{dx}=g-\dfrac{kv}{m}$$
$$\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{kv}{m}=g$$
This is a linear ODE. We have the integrating factor: $e^{kt/m}$
Therefore the solution to the ODE is:
$$v\cdot e^{kt/m}=\frac{mg}{k}e^{kt/m}+c$$
Assuming velocity at time $0$ was $0$, we get $c=-\frac{mg}{k}$
, and simplifying furthur we arrive at:
$$v(t)=\frac{mg}{k}\left(1-e^{-kt/m}\right)$$